# Onclick event on a paragraph is triggered under the paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wich to replace a paragraph with a textarea tag when clicking on the paragraph, the textarea should contain the text that was in the paragraph:

```
<div id="right"><p><pre><?php echo $descri; ?></pre></p></div>
```

Jquery script :

```
$(function(){
  $('#right').on('click', 'p', function(){
    var $p = $(this);
    var old = $p.html();

    if(/<textarea rows="4" cols="40" id="descri" name="descri"/.test(old))
      return;

    $p.html('<textarea rows="4" cols="40" id="descri" name="descri" value="' + old + '"/>')
       .find('textarea')
       .focus()
       .on('blur', function(){
         var value = this.value;
         $.post('listener_updates.php', {description: value})
          .done(function(){
            $p.html(value);
          })
          .fail(function(){
            $p.html(old);
            alert('Could not update title');
          });
       });
  });
});
```

Now when I click on the paragraph text, nothing happens but when I click a little under the paragraph text, then the textarea appears and is empty.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Also, your jquery selection is trying to select an ID but in your html it's a class.

Comment: But if I don't put the pre tag, the text echoed will not be formated (writen in the same line) and it's not what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you can't put a [`pre` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-pre-element) inside a [`p` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element), so the browser's correcting the invalid DOM. The content model of `p` is **phrasing content**, but `pre` isn't valid in phrasing content, only **flow content**.

When you give this to Chrome:

```
<div class="right"><p><pre>This is the text</pre></p></div>
```

...it actually creates this DOM:

```
<div class"right"><p></p><pre>This is the text</pre><p></p></div>
```

Note that the `pre` is no longer in any `p`.

If you want the `pre`, simply use `pre` on its own (without the `p`). `pre` is a lot like like `p`: They both have the same content model, they're both valid in the same places, and they're both `display: block` by default.

Alternately, if your only goal is not to have line wrapping and other such, on modern browsers you can get rid of the `pre` (keeping the `p` or using a `div` if the semantics of `p` aren't appropriate) and use the CSS [`white-space` property](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/) (e.g., `white-space: pre`) instead.

---

Re your comment below:

> but I can't get the text inside the pre tag to show on the textarea

Just put the `pre`'s `contents()` into the `textarea`, put the `textarea` in the DOM where you want it, and remove or hide the `pre`. This removes it, for instance: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/eXAdaNA/1/edit)

```
$(".right").on("click", "pre", function() {
  var $pre = $(this);
  var $textarea = $("<textarea>");
  $textarea.append($pre.contents());
  $pre.replaceWith($textarea);
  return false;
});
```

Comment: But if I don't put the pre tag, the text echoed will not be formated (writen in the same line) and it's not what I want. what do you suggest I should do to keep the pre, replae p tag by a div tag ?

Comment: Cool it's working, but I can't get the text inside the pre tag to show on the textarea can you please help ?